# I want to check in my path if there is a pair of value.... suppose if my path is 1 2 3 4 5 i want to check if (2 3) occurs in my path or not

Tags: java

This function prints my path.I wanted to check if in this path i have certain pair of values 
(2 3) 
or (5 6)
How can i do that?

```
private void printPath(LinkedList<Integer> visited) {



            for (Integer node : visited) {

                System.out.print(node);
                System.out.print(" ");

            }



            System.out.println();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
private void printPath(LinkedList<Integer> visited) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer node : visited) {
        stringBuilder.append(node).append(" ");
    }

    String stringToPrint = stringBuilder.toString();

    boolean hasValues = stringToPrint.contains("2 3"); //your values here

    System.out.println(stringToPrint);
    //System.out.println(hasValues);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Alex :-)

Comment: Hello If in a path the pair (2 3 ) occured then i should store and display it.How can i do it.

Comment: @PriyadharshiniRavi what do you mean by storing?   You can write   if(stringToPrint.contains("2 3")) {  System.out.println(stringToPrint);//some storing algorithm here }

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
Collections.indexOfSubList(sourceList, Arrays.asList(2, 3)) >= 0
```

Here some TestCode:

```
    LinkedList<Integer> sourceList = new LinkedList<>();
    sourceList.add(1);
    sourceList.add(2);
    sourceList.add(3);
    sourceList.add(4);
    sourceList.add(5);

    System.out.println(Collections.indexOfSubList(sourceList, Arrays.asList(2, 4)) >= 0);
    System.out.println(Collections.indexOfSubList(sourceList, Arrays.asList(2, 3)) >= 0);
```

prints

```
 false
 true
```